# Free software for batch basic editing and down-sampling

Tags: video-editor, encoding

I have a bunch of TV shows in HD that I want to down-sample to SD and at the same time strip out the titles and credits.

Handbrake has great encoding and can handle batches, but I can't find a way to set in and out points.

I've tried the free [ShotCut](https://www.shotcutapp.com), which is perfectly capable to doing easy edits, but seems to be really slow.

Are they any recommendations for doing this sort of easy, but bulk work for macOS?

Comment: MPEG Streamclip or ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can do this with `VLC` 3.0+ or via the command line.

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Transcode_multiple_videos/

This can be done using the transcode/streaming options via the file menu in the graphical app. You can set the in and out and select all te files to process, as well as the codec and container format.

Comment: Can you explain, at least in broad strokes, how to do what the OP is asking for?

Comment: Woops, thought I’d posted this as a comment rather than an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @alan-kael-ball. I downloaded the latest nightly build and had a look at the transcoding options in the GUI. No options there to set in and out points. I'll look into the command line more and see if there is anything there...

Comment: I think if you do it from the wizard, you can select a playlist and the in/out times can be inputted under it. Heading is `partial extract`

Answer (score 0):

The exact command to do this in `ffmpeg` under Linux is:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -to 01:00:00 \
       -i input.avi \
       -map_metadata -1 \   
       -c:v libx264 -strict -2 \
       -r 30 \
       -s 960x540 \
       -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 384K
       output.avi
```

For Windows: same as above but strip out everything after the `\` (including the `\`) and put it all on the same line.

where the following means:

- `-ss 00:00:00`: strip 10 seconds from the beginning of the movie.
- `-to 01:00:00`: encode everything up to 1h and drop anything afterwards
- `input.avi`: the input file
- `-map_metadata -1`: strip out all metadata
- `-r 30`: 30 Frames per second
- `-s 960x540`: Resolution for SD
- `-c:a libmp3lame -b:a 384K`: Use MP3 VBR encoding up to a max of 384KB/s